# Reading and writing YAML files via Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I'm writing a little python script (python 3.7) that should read and write YAML files. At the moment I'm at the point where I just want to read a given YAML file. I imported the YAML library and tried to read the file. The problem that I'm having at the moment is that the output is not nested as it is in the original file.

How can I write a YAML file in a structured way as shown in the section below.

## My Code:

```
import yaml

with open("/Users/Ilumeyss/Desktop/05_PS_ITM/xDQ_Datenqualitaetsvereinbarung_1003222_2018-10-16_v22yaml.sec", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        print(yaml.safe_load(stream))
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

## This is what I'd like to have:

> projectElements: 
>      company:
>           supplier:
>               dataSupplierInformation:
>                   name:
>   "Textilfabrik GmbH & Co. KG"
>                   address:
>   {strasse: "Industriestr 1", plz: "72555", ort: "Metzingen", land:
>   "Germany"}
>                   xdqNr:
>   1001001
>                           dataUserInformation:
>                                   name:
>   "Handel24 Deutschland AG"
>                                   address:
>   {strasse: "Handelsweg 42", plz: "74078", ort: "Heilbronn", land:
>   "Germany"}
>                                   xdqNr:
>   1001002
>                   documentinformation:
>                           dokumentname:
>   "Datenqualitaetsvereinbarung"
>                           xdqNr:
>   1003222

## This is what I get so far:

> {'projectElements': {'company': {'supplier':
>   {'dataSupplierInformation': {'name': 'Textilfabrik GmbH & Co. KG',
>   'address':
>
> ...and so on

Comment: Reading a YAML file gives you a dictionary, which looks like what you've shown. You can write it to another YAML file using `yaml.dump`.

Comment: The data has been stored in a nested form in a `dict` from what I can see. If your only problem is that it isn't printing in a nested format, use `pprint` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

In order to print a YAML document as you have loaded it, you should dump
the loaded data to stdout. I do recommend to use `ruamel.yaml` as it supports
this kind of round-tripping much better than PyYAML (disclaimer: I am the author of ruamel.yaml).
PyYAML only supports YAML 1.1 and that was outdated back in 2009.

If your input is in `xDQ_Datenqualitaetsvereinbarung_1003222_2018-10-16_v22yaml.sec`:

```
projectElements: 
  company:
    supplier:
      dataSupplierInformation:
        name: "Textilfabrik GmbH & Co. KG"

        address: {strasse: "Industriestr 1", plz: "72555", ort: "Metzingen", land: "Germany"}

        xdqNr: 1001001
      dataUserInformation:
        name: "Handel24 Deutschland AG"
        address: {strasse: "Handelsweg 42", plz: "74078", ort: "Heilbronn", land: "Germany"}
        xdqNr: 1001002
      documentinformation:
        dokumentname: "Datenqualitaetsvereinbarung"
        xdqNr: 1003222
```

And your program:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

infile = Path('xDQ_Datenqualitaetsvereinbarung_1003222_2018-10-16_v22yaml.sec')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(infile)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

your output will be:

```
projectElements:
  company:
    supplier:
      dataSupplierInformation:
        name: "Textilfabrik GmbH & Co. KG"

        address: {strasse: "Industriestr 1", plz: "72555", ort: "Metzingen", land: "Germany"}

        xdqNr: 1001001
      dataUserInformation:
        name: "Handel24 Deutschland AG"
        address: {strasse: "Handelsweg 42", plz: "74078", ort: "Heilbronn", land: "Germany"}
        xdqNr: 1001002
      documentinformation:
        dokumentname: "Datenqualitaetsvereinbarung"
        xdqNr: 1003222
```

and you cannot get that exact same output with PyYAML in any easy way.

Comment: Hey @Anthon, sorry for the late answer.

I'm getting a composer error:
ruamel.yaml.composer.ComposerError: expected a single document in the stream
  in "/Users/Ilumeyss/Downloads/QualiVereinb/xDQ_Datenqualitaetsvereinbarung_1003222_2018-10-16_v22yaml.sec", line 17, column 1
but found another document
  in "/Users/Ilumeyss/Downloads/QualiVereinb/xDQ_Datenqualitaetsvereinbarung_1003222_2018-10-16_v22yaml.sec", line 135, column 1

Comment: Hey @Anthon, it works now the yaml file had some wrong sections. Thanks a lot.
How can I write a new Yaml file with ruamel.yaml?

Comment: `.dump()` takes as second parameter a stream (that can be written to, such as a file opened for writing) or a `pathlib.Path()` instance.